# Upload image file (NOT selected via form, just within a folder) to mysql via PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I'm just unclear how to format this- in the past I have have users upload an image they select from their computer via a form and javascript like so:

```
$("#uploadimage").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();


        $.ajax({
        url: "../php/upload.php", // Url to which the request is send
        type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
        data: new FormData(this), // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs (i.e. form fields and values)
        contentType: false,       // The content type used when sending data to the server.
        cache: false,             // To unable request pages to be cached
        processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false
        success: function(data)   // A function to be called if request succeeds
        {

        }
        });
        }));
```

Which sends the file to a php script:

```
if(isset($_FILES["file"]["type"]))
{
$validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$maxsize = 99999999;
$temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$file_extension = end($temporary);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < $maxsize)//Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
&& in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)) {

$size = getimagesize($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$type = $size['mime'];
$imgfp = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], 'rb');
$size = $size[3];
$name = $_FILES['file']['name'];

$sql = new mysqli("localhost","username","password","sqlserver");
$imgfp64 = base64_encode(stream_get_contents($imgfp));
$update = "UPDATE sqlserver.imageblob set image='".$imgfp64."', image_type='".$type."', image_name='".$name."', image_size='".$size."' where user_id=".$account['id'];
$sql->query($update);
```

And then I have been able to display the image like this and echoing HTML:

```
$imgdata = $array['image']; //store img src
     $src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$imgdata;
```

But now I need to upload an image file that i have STORED already in a folder i.e. `../images/image1.png` NOT an uploaded file from a form.

Ideally I would write:

```
$imgfile = "../images/image1.png"
```

Then plug this into my php in place of `$_FILES['file']['name']` but I do not know how to properly write this out. I am new to mysql and am getting error messages just passing a file name like above.

How can I upload an image that I already have in my folder to mysql table?

What I have tried:

[image]

Comment: Maybe just create an html page, constructed with php, that loads all the images into it. each image can have an onclick handler that will assign some javascript variable with it's path. Then, you can send an ajax request using that path. Hope this helps.

Comment: Try `on('click', (function(e){}));`

Comment: @divinemaniac no I don't need to echo the image necessarily just need to store it in mysql table

Comment: If you want to get a file from your file system, you will want to use `file_get_contents($filename);` then store that in your db.

Comment: @Rasclatt I've updated my question. Still unsure as to how to format this - What am I doing wrong with the code above?

Comment: Where is your form? I hope your form has an `id` tag of `uploadimage`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [DirectoryIterator](http://de.php.net/manual/en/directoryiterator.construct.php):

Save this file to your `images` folder and run it:

```
<?php

    $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
    $dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
    foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
        if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {

            $extension = strtolower(pathinfo($fileinfo->getFilename(), PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); /* GET EXTENSION OF FILE */

            if(in_array($extension, $validextensions)){ /* IF FILE IS IMAGE; JPEG, JPG, OR PNG */

                /* CHECK IF IMAGE IS ALREADY IN THE DATABASE */
                $check = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM image_table WHERE image_col = ?"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY TABLE AND COLUMN NAME */
                $check->bind_param("s", $fileinfo->getFilename());
                $check->execute();
                $check->store_result();
                $noofrows = $check->num_rows;
                $check->close();

                if($noofrows == 0){ /* IF IMAGE NAME IS NOT YET IN THE DATABASE */
                    /* INSERT FILE NAME TO DATABASE */
                    $stmt = $sql->query("INSERT INTO image_table (image_col) VALUES (?)"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY TABLE AND COLUMN NAME */
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $fileinfo->getFilename());
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $stmt->close();
                }

            }
        }
    }

?>
```

Above will save the image name to your database.

And when you want to display the images, just run this query:

```
$getimg = $sql->prepare("SELECT image_col FROM image_table"); /* REPLACE NECESSARY TABLE AND COLUMN NAME */
$getimg->execute();
$getimg->bind_result($image);
while($getimg->fetch()){
    echo '<img src="images/'.$image.'">';
}
$getimg->close();
```

Comment: No - this isn't the problem. I dont want to have a form of any kind. No form and no selecting an image. I just want to manually populate my mysql table (its a user account) with an image that I have on my computer when a function within my PHP class is called

Comment: I want to do this all in PHP - no javascript, no form. Just stick and image in a mysql table